# Where & Top interaction in SQL Server View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, sql-view

Do you know how to persuade SQL Server to consider WHERE clauses inside the view?
It looks like SQL Server is running just my view, evaluating the TOP 1, then applying the "where id=N" clause to filter the view's result set.
Example:

```
create table mytable ( id int, name varchar(64) );

insert into mytable values ( 5, 'BOB' );
insert into mytable values ( 5, 'ROBERT' );
insert into mytable values ( 5, 'SMITH, ROBERT' );
insert into mytable values ( 8, 'A.J.' );
insert into mytable values ( 8, 'Al J.' );
insert into mytable values ( 8, 'Albert Johnston' );

select * from mytable;

+----+-----------------+
: id : name            :
+----+-----------------+
:  5 : BOB             :
:  5 : ROBERT          :
:  5 : SMITH, ROBERT   :
:  8 : A.J.            :
:  8 : Al J.           :
:  8 : Albert Johnston :
+----+-----------------+

create view myview as
   select top 1 id, name
   from mytable
   order by len(name) desc
```

Problem:

```
-- bad, empty result set
-- (I want this to answer 5, 'SMITH, ROBERT')
select * from myview where id = 5
```

These work as expected:

```
-- good, answers 8, 'Albert Johnston'
select * from myview

-- good, also answers 8, 'Albert Johnston'
select * from myview where id = 8
```

Now without the view:

```
-- good, answers 5, 'SMITH, ROBERT'
select top 1 id, name
from mytable
where id = 5
order by len(name) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you want to create something like this, I would suggest to use a something that returns you a value using a where, so better to create a `Table-Valued User-Defined Function`

```
Create dbo.YourFunction
(
  @parameter id
)
returns table
as
return select top 1 id, name
   from mytable
   where id = @parameter 
   order by len(name) desc
```

and use it like

```
select * from dbo.yourFunction(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view will always return `Albert Johnston` since it is not possible to force it to evaluate the outer where condition first. You need something like following, will give you the name/Id with max length for each id group:

```
select
    name,
    id
from
(
    select
        name,
        id,
        row_number() OVER (partition by id order by len(name) desc) as [len]
    from 
        theTable
) As tbl1
where [len] = 1
```